# Newtonsoft Array With Index Key Deserialize

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I use newtonsoft.Net library for Deserialize/Serialize Objects.

Could I Deserialize the following json  as Array of "OfferPixel" ?

All of arrays has index number for each  Item on service. So "Offerpixel" object seem subItem of Index Number.

```
{
"data": {
      "1": {
        "OfferPixel": {
          "id": "1",
          "affiliate_id": "1009",
          "offer_id": "7",
          "status": "deleted",
          "code": "",
          "type": "url",
          "modified": "2012-02-16 10:07:33",
          "goal_id": null
        }
      },
      "2": {
        "OfferPixel": {
          "id": "2",
          "affiliate_id": "1011",
          "offer_id": "7",
          "status": "deleted",
          "code": "",
          "type": "code",
          "modified": "2013-08-16 07:27:20",
          "goal_id": null
        }
      },
      "3": {
        "OfferPixel": {
          "id": "3",
          "affiliate_id": "1010",
          "offer_id": "7",
          "status": "deleted",
          "code": "",
          "type": "image",
          "modified": "2013-01-31 12:01:57",
          "goal_id": null
        }
       },
    "errors": [],
    "errorMessage": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
var list = JObject.Parse(json)
                    .Descendants()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Where(p => p.Name == "OfferPixel")
                    .Select(x => x.Value.ToObject<OfferPixel>())
                    .ToList();
```

---

```
public class OfferPixel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string affiliate_id { get; set; }
    public string offer_id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string modified { get; set; }
    public object goal_id { get; set; }
}
```